# Change Gitlab account in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, gitlab, repository

I have a project in my personal Gitlab account and I moved this project to work account. I set my personal account in Android Studio and now I want to change to work account but I don't know how to do this. I read about this and I select "Do not save, forget passwords after start". Now I get Login in Gitlab popup and set the new email and password, but I get the below error.

> remote: HTTP Basic: Access denied Authentication failed for
>   'https://gitlab.com/OldAccount/Projectame.git

I am new in Gitlab and I don't know how to fix that or I don't know, I can change my local repository to another Gitlab account with all of the previous push and commits.

Comment: try Settings -> Version control -> GitHub, there you should see your account.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Yeah, I see my new account in Github part in settings but after I set the new account and password in popup page after I select push, I get the above error like the AS to try to connect to the old account

Comment: did you removed your personal account? also you can go to project root and to .git directory, there you can find "config" file, check what if you have there a username.

Comment: Thanks. I checked "config" file and in the URL part sets old account manually, I changed this to the new account but again I want to push anything, I get the above error with the  new account

Answer (score 0):

I always use github. I seldom use GitLab. But for switching between my works I use remote repositories. For example I have personal account on GitLab and I have another work account on GitLab.

> `git remote add upstream ssh or http url`
>
> git remote -v 
>   *to check remote repositories*

You can add two or more repositories and can push and merge them.

I think This may help. For more information you can find here.
https://git-scm.com/docs/git-remote